# File is stored couple of times instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I upload a file it is stored X times where X is the time count you upload it. If I try to upload it three times in a row it will store one file, two files, three files which gives us 6 in total.

Why does that happen?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#uploadButton").on('click', function() {
    const job_id = $(this).attr("data-item");

    $("#cvForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("cvForm"));

      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/job/apply/' + job_id,
        data: form_data,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Form is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="CVModalUpload" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="cvForm" name="cv" method="post" action="{{ path('student_candidate', {'id':job.id}) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" name="cv[file]" class="custom-file-input" id="uploadGroup" aria-describedby="uploadButton">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploadGroup">Choose CV</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="submit" name="cv[send]" class="btn btn btn-primary shadow rounded-0" id="uploadButton" data-item="{{ job.id }}">Upload CV</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ form_row(form._token) }}
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you're nesting your event handlers. Move `submit()` *outside* of `click()`. You'll then need a method of retrieving the `job_id` from the DOM, but we can't really help with that without seeing your HTML

Comment: Oh, right! I've added the form that's used.I would love to see some better approach in order to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're nesting your event handlers. To fix this move `submit()` outside of `click()`.

That said, now that you've added the HTML to the question, I can see that you don't need the `click` handler at all. You can simply read the `data-item` from the button when the form is submit. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#cvForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form_data = new FormData(this); // note 'this' here
    let job_id = $('#uploadButton').data('item'); // note 'data()' here

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/job/apply/' + job_id,
      data: form_data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its propably because of the location where you implemented `submit()`. You should propably move it outside of the `click()`-eventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have placed your submit button inside a form. Now whenever a button is pressed inside a form, it automatically submits the form. In your case form is submitting two times, once when button is clicked and second time inside your click handler.

Easy solution to this is, just change type attribute of your submit button to "button".